# A problem when Updating the offline package of visual studio 2019 (it downloads the installer then nothing happens)

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019

I have download an offline package of visual studio 2019 a year or more ago, since that date, and when a new update is released I use this command `vs_Community.exe --layout pathToVS2019OfflinePackage --lang en-US` to update my visual studio 2019 offline package.

But this time, when trying to do what I do each time:

`vs_Community.exe --layout pathToVS2019OfflinePackage --lang en-US`

[image]

Then it downloads the last version of the installer

[image]

Then nothing happens (Supposed in this step the update starts).

**Why the update doesn't start (I didn't change any settings)?**

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the offline update VS’s process is like this:

**On the machine with network**

1). Move the existing layout folder from the machine without network to this machine.

2). Download the latest version of VS bootstrapper file(.exe file from [official website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)).

3). Open CMD and `cd` to the directory where you saved the downloaded .exe file.

4). Type command like `vs_community.exe –layout XXXX\XXXXX\XXXX –lang en-US` and wait for it completes.

**On the machine without network(offline)**

5). Move the updated layout folder to this machine.

6). Launch Visual Studio Installer > find VS 2019 > click Update.

Looks like you are blocked on step 4), you need to make sure that you have **downloaded** and **are using the latest .exe file** and make sure that these operations are performed on a **network based** machine.

Details: [Update a network-based installation of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you, I did that before and the update didn't start.

Comment: I have tried another simple way and has worked. I have replaced the old VS bootstrapper file with the latest version of it and it worked (the update start and successfully finished).

Comment: Happy to hear that, sounds like the issue is, not changing to use the latest version of VS bootstrapper file.